# Android RecyclerView is null

Tags: java, android, xml

It was working all the time before, but suddently it doesn't, even though i didn't even change the code... I'm getting a null reference on my RecyclerView instance, as the exception tells me...
Here is my Java Code:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter rvadapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager;

    static ArrayList<String> itemTexte;

    File dir;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notizen");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            try {
                dir.mkdirs();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        itemTexte = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        rvLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(RecyclerViewActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);

        rvadapter = new RvAdapterKlasse(RecyclerViewActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvadapter);

        notizenSetup();
    }
```

The error is in `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);`
Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="at.wurz.david.recyclerviewtemplate.RecyclerViewActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error:

```
04-09 10:35:23.131 15155-15155/at.wurz.david.recyclerviewtemplate D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-09 10:35:23.133 15155-15155/at.wurz.david.recyclerviewtemplate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: at.wurz.david.recyclerviewtemplate, PID: 15155
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.wurz.david.recyclerviewtemplate/at.wurz.david.recyclerviewtemplate.RecyclerViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at at.wurz.david.recyclerviewtemplate.RecyclerViewActivity.onCreate(RecyclerViewActivity.java:76)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

I searched for the error, but all topics are at least 1 year old and say that google already fixed that error.

Comment: Where is the error stacktrace ?

Comment: Edited! If you can read something out of it... :D

Comment: You have instantiate RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager;

Comment: Your object is unable to find the RecyclerView, may be the error of support library.. clean the project and try to add the support library again.

Comment: sounds good... :) happy codding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clean and build, it should fix the error and try to add the support library again